# Reversing a string in Python, what is wrong in two of my codes

Tags: string, python-3.x

1.

```
a='kasturi'
b=a[len(a)::-1]
print(b) # gives irutsak
```

2.

```
a='kasturi'
for i in range(len(a)-1,-1,-1):
    print(a[i],end='')
print(a) # gives irutsak
```

In the Second code, for i in range(0,len(a)-1), here increment operator (1) is hidden. In increment case, the loop traverses from lower value to higher and in case of decrement, the loop traverses from higher value to lower but in decrement, it is necessary to mention decrement operator

In the First code, the slicing is done from max of length to (-1) as the slicing do not count the last index

Comment: Are you getting the desired reversal?

Comment: Use a[::-1]  only this one

Comment: @Kasturi Yes. Mentioning decrement from higher to lower in a must. Else for-loop doesn't move at all. Cause by default python is set to increment. So in the case of decrement, it needs a mention.